what is the error in my code (javascript), why it is not looping over my array?
My script is not looping over my array. There is always an error showing. Please find what's the error is. I really can't find it. I tried this multiple time but its not working. Im trying to make a tic toe toe project. I tried to use getElementsByClassName and all of that but its still not working. Is there any typo or some rookie mistake.


let avar = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
let count = 1;

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

  avar[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (count % 2 === 0) {
      avar[i].innerText = "X";
    } else {
      avar[i].innerText = "O";
    }
    count++;
  });
}
<div id="container">
  <div id="zero" class="input">zero</div>
  <div id="one" class="input">one</div>
  <div id="two" class="input">two</div>
  <div id="three" class="input">three</div>
  <div id="four" class="input">four</div>
  <div id="five" class="input">five</div>
  <div id="six" class="input">six</div>
  <div id="seven" class="input">seven</div>
  <div id="eight" class="input">eight</div>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>




Your js could be simplified with the usage of forEach and removing repetitive code: `let avar = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
avar.forEach((element, i) => {
element.addEventListener('click', () => {
element.textContent = (i % 2 === 0) ? 'O' : 'X';
});
});`

put the let keyword infront of the i variable: for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++). btw forEach is less effecient and a non breakable loop so probably keep the habit of using 'for' you've just missed a keyword
